# Rails - Many-to-Many Relationship - Data Issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a pretty newb question, about a many-to-many relationship I've created, and pulling the correct data from the child.

What I have is 2 Models, one called Order and another Status. I have a migration named CreateOrdersStatuses to join the two tables.

In the ruby console, I'm having difficulties pulling information of the child via the parent, for example:

I have assigned my first order a status, and the console gives me the following read out:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > order.statuses
 => [#<Status id: 1, name: "New", created_at: "2010-11-18 20:19:12", updated_at: "2010-11-18 20:19:12">]
```

However, for my view, I'm trying to display an order's status, so I've been trying the following in the console order.statuses.name - which I thought would give me the print out of "New". Instead I'm only able to pull "Status" when attempting this. For example:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > order.statuses.name
=> "Status"
```

I believe my issue is syntax related when trying to pull my order's status name? I can provide the models/migrations if necessary, I was just thinking it is a syntax issue since I'm a newb :).

Thanks all.

Comment: Just a question, are you sure a many-to-many relation is correct in this case? If an order can have several statuses at the same time, for example it could be both New, In Progress and Closed simultaneously which does not sound right to me. I would sugest that you change it to a belongs_to association where an order belongs_to a status and that a status has_many orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`order.statuses.name` won't return "New", because `order.statuses` is a collection (you see rectangular brackets in your first output). So there's no sense in doing `order.statuses.name`. You can do `order.statuses[0].name`, for instance.

Nevertheless, `order.statuses.name` doesn't throw an error, because an association actually has a method `name` that returns the name of the association's class. In your case the class of `statuses` association is `Status`, so this method returns "Status".

Comment: Thank you so much neutrino. That does make sense sir, I really appreciate it. I was basically asking it to tell me the class' name of the statuses collection I created, not asking for the first item's "name" in the array? Thanks once again, I'm truly grateful.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid icky array-index notation "[0]", you can do instead:

```
order.statuses.first.name
```

assuming that your Order model

```
has_many :statuses
```

Comment: It's set to has_and_belongs_to_many so this too will work. A quick question related to this if you know: When I create my new order's, they are not associated with any statuses to begin. Is there a way to set it up so when I create an order, an initial relationship is set is set to to my first Status? I haven't had any luck setting a :default in the migration, likely because my Order model doesn't include a fk to status.

Comment: you can add a method named 'initialize' to the model, where you can set an associated status if none are already set. 
Default values on models are tricky in Rails. There are also callback hooks like 'before_initialize' or 'after_initialize' that you might want to try.